# Shiva and Mohini

Tags: vishnu, shiva

I am more interested in knowing why did the incident between Shiva and Mohini happen. Is it merely to accept Homosexuality in Hinduism?

He says the seed did not take fruition, but was Lord Ayyappa born out of this Union?

Answer (score 0):

Various incidents have Of Shiv-Mohini have been reported in various Puranas. But what people didn't understand is that Mohini is the maya (illusion) form of Lord Vishnu himself. Once the purpose is served it returns back to Lord Vishnu. Maya can enchant anyone even the Lord Shiv, supreme aesthetic was enchanted for a moment, result of which was skanda or lord Ayappa as regional deity.

"Both are same in all sense yet both are different in all sense."

Sanatan Dharma has no issue with homosexuality, neither it promotes it nor it disapproves it. It's your life you are free to choose any path.

Comment: Thank you so much, I am beginning to understand what you have stated. It is more clear to me

Comment: Happy to help.;)

Comment: You can also cast up votes on the posts you have found informative or useful @BizYankee